# Adding flags when install gem via `bundle install`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I am trying to install mysql2 gem like below and this works

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"
```

however, I want to install the gem via `Gemfile` so I executed

```
bundle config build.mysql2 -v '0.4.10' -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"
```

but this does not work and I see a exception

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/ext/mysql2
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/bin/ruby -I /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20230506-62617-pmasf2.rb extconf.rb --with-ldflags\=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib\
--with-cppflags\=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: I _think_ `gem install` doesn't get as picky about dependencies as `bundler` does, which could explain why `gem install` works, but `bundler` doesn't. Have you looked at the dependencies and made sure they install properly?

Comment: Version difference? Looks like the first command will install `v.0.5.5` which has some openssl related fixes